# c# form losing focus

Tags: c#, winforms

When i run my application with visual studio IDE, the application runs fine. When i run directly the executable it is not running fine.

My app creates two forms. First form losts focus when the second form is about to create. The first form UI frezzes when i run directly executable.

Please give any suggestions how to debug the problem.

Regards
Raju

Comment: in what moment do you show the 2nd form?

Comment: My app creates first form at startup. Second form would be created based on some condition which happens 30 sec after start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the First form property Topmost to true solved the prolem.